# ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection comes from a loop with heavy memory access

Tags: java, oracle

I have a loop with heavy memory access from oracle.

```
    int firstResult = 0;
    int maxResult = 500;
    int targetTotal = 8000; // more or less

    int phase = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<= targetTotal; i += maxResult) {
        try {
            Session session = .... init hibernate session ...
            // Start Transaction
            List<Accounts> importableInvAcList = ...getting list using session and firstResult-maxResult...

            List<ContractData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<ErrorData> errorDataList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Accounts account : importableInvAcList) {
                ... Converting 500 Accounts object to ContractData object ...
                ... along with 5 more database call using existing session ...
                .. On converting The object we generate thousands of ErrorData...

                dataList.add(.. converted account to Contract data ..);
                errorDataList.add(.. generated error data ..);
            }

            dataList.stream().forEach(session::save); // 500 data

            errorDataList.stream().forEach(session::save); // 10,000-5,000 data

            ... Commit Transaction ...
            phase++;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return;
        }
    }
```

On the second phase (2nd loop) the Exception comes  out. Sometimes Exception is coming out in 3rd or fifth phase.

I also checked the Runtime Memory.

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long total = runtime.totalMemory();
    long free = runtime.freeMemory();
    long used = total - free;
    long max = runtime.maxMemory();
```

And in the second phase the status was below for sample...

Used: **1022 MB**, Free: **313 MB**, Total Allocated: **1335 MB**

**Stack Trace is here...**

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1463)
        at ibbl.remote.tx.TxSessionImpl.beginTx(TxSessionImpl.java:41)
        at ibbl.remote.tx.TxController.initPersistence(TxController.java:70)
        at com.ibbl.data.util.CDExporter2.run(CDExporter2.java:130)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
```

Noted that, this process running in a `Thread`, and there are 3 similar `Thread` running at a time.
**Why this Exception hangs out after the loop running a while ?**

Comment: What does this ".... init hibernate session ..." do? Are you creating a new connection to the database for each iteration of the loop? Why don't you initialize that session **outside** of the loop?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Each loop takes almost 30 sec to finish. That is why I generate session in loop and commit/close in it. Is this happen any problem ?

Comment: It's better to keep the _connection_ open (assuming that's the same as the "session"). Constantly opening and closing a (physical) connection is not a good idea (unless you have a connection pool in the background)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry.. I have tried keeping the session outside the loop, but same problem comes out.

Answer (score 1):

> > there are 3 similar Thread running at a time.

If your code creates a total of 3 Threads, then, optimally, you need only 3 Oracle Connections. Create all of them before any Thread is created. Create the Threads, assign each Thread a Connection, then start the Threads.

Chances are good, though, that your code might be way too aggressively consuming resources on whatever machine is hosting it. Even if you eliminate the ORA-12518, the RDBMS server may "go south". By "go south", I mean if your application is consuming too many resources the machine hosting it or the machine hosting the RDBMS server may "panic" or something equally dreadful.

Comment: Each thread may takes 30 minute to finish. Is there any problem to keep alive the session for this long time ?

Comment: I've seen traces of sessions that do work for more than 24 hours. But you probably should clarify what you mean by "keep alive". That is a special phrase and I want to make sure you mean what you say before commenting further.

Comment: I did mean "keep the session open for long time". However thank you for your suggestion. I thought session should not keep open for a long time. Now I have instantiate the session outside the loop. Thanks.